# How to get QGIS layer information saved in JSON format?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, metadata

I have called a URL to load imagery. Once the imagery is loaded in QGIS, I want the information of this layer (metadata), as seen in the below picture, to be stored in JSON format. 
NOTE: It can be opened by right clicking the imagery layer --> Properties --> Information.

[image: Layer Information]

I have tried the below code but it returns QgsLayerMetadata object with null values:

```
a = iface.activeLayer().metadata()
```

How to save this information in JSON file?

Comment: put the bits you want into a dict and then write to file?