# How to export layer with metadata in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, layers, metadata

I have set some metadata for my layer that I would like to export. I export the layer using the following:

```
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer,"path/layer.shp",'utf-8',driverName='ESRI Shapefile')
```

However the saved layer does not contain the metadata. How can I export the layer and keep the metadata?

Comment: Try exporting as a geopackage

Comment: Thanks, I see how this would work but I need to export as shapefiles for data sharing.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "metadata"? The information tab? The metadata tab? It's possible to save the QMD file with PyQGIS.

Comment: Sadly, shapefiles are old and obsolete so have no concept of metadata

Answer (score 1):

There are no built-in functions to achieve what you want. Get the reference to the `QgsLayerMetadata` object from this answer [How to get QGIS layer information saved in JSON format?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315819/how-to-get-qgis-layer-information-saved-in-json-format) and as stated in comment, write your own metadata as JSON in a separated file.

Alternatively, you can write the layer definition with something like below. It will contains several information including metadata in an XML file

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
# mylayer.qlr is hard coded here but it could be determined from "layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()"
# if it's a filename or the layer name "layer.name()" or layer id "layer.id()"
with open('mylayer.qlr', 'w') as f:
    f.write(QgsLayerDefinition.exportLayerDefinitionLayers([layer], QgsReadWriteContext()).toString())
```

Comment: Ah too bad... I did that but it's not as cool as having the metadata embedded in the shapefile... Thanks for your answer